# Auto Hide Android Bottom Bar when soft keyboard minimize/close

Tags: android

I ran to problem when softkeyboard is minimized the bottom bar android is still there even when already use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    //ConstraintLayout rl = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a problem using this listener

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        onWindowFocusChanged(true);
                    }
                }
            });
```